# Prevent full page image in multicols

Tags: floats, multicol

While placing a full-width image in the multicols environment using

```
\begin{figure*} ...
\end{figure*}
```

if the figure is larger than some fraction of the page, it takes up a whole page on its own, with copious white space above and below it.  Is there a way to prevent the figure from taking a whole page, forcing the figure back to the top of the page and filling the white space below it with text?

Comment: I managed to solve this problem myself by accident:  while multicols does not support image floating, using the \begin{figure*}[htb] will prevent page floating and prevent the creation of a full-page image.

Comment: Could you make your comment here into a self-answer?

Answer (score 1):

> if the figure is larger than some fraction of the page,

instead of only forcing the placement (btw, I suggest to use only `[tb]`), you can try to adapt the figure to the page width:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{your-figure-file}
\end{figure*}
```